# Is there a way to tell R# that after I run a a method, certain class variables won't be null

Tags: resharper

Consider the following code:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int? NullableInt { get; set; }

    private bool DoPreChecks()
    {
        if(NullableInt == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public bool DoTest()
    {
        if(!DoPreChecks())
            return false;

        //Here R# tells me that "nullableInt" may be null
        if (NullableInt.Value > 10)
        {
            // Do something
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

R# would be correct to worry that "NullableInt.Value" may be null when I reference it in "DoTest", except that if it was, then "DoPreChecks" would have returned false and that means I would never have gotten to this line.  I was looking at R#'s code annotations and I see I can tell it what output to expect under limited conditions and it seems like that may be something I could leverage here, but I don't see any way to tell it that when the output is true/false/null/notnull, then a class variable (which has nothing to do with the input or output) will have a certain value type (true/false/null/notnull).  Can something like this be done?

The use case here is this -- I have a dozen methods that all rely on the same preconditions, including several class variables being initialized.  Rather than putting all those checks in each method, I want to have them all run the "DoPreChecks" method and if it returns true, we're good to go.  The problem is that R# can't follow that and thinks I have lots of possible null reference exceptions.  I could:

1. Ignore the errors completely and just tolerate wiggly lines everywhere
2. Disable and restore the warning at the beginning and ending of these methods
3. Disable the warning 1 line at a time
4. Do null checks or assertions before each use

The problem with each is...

1. Violates company policy to just ignore warnings
2. Disabling this check over large swaths of code would be worse than ignoring individual warnings because other valid issues may be there, but get disabled
3. This would require a LOT of R# comments, thus negating the helpfulness of DoPreChecks method
4. Same as #3

Right now I'm leaning toward getting an exception on the policy and just ignoring the warnings, but if there is a way to tell R# what is going on, that would be a much better solution.  Can it be done without adding parameters or complicating the return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contract annotation in ReSharper that sets up a relation between return value of a method and nullness of a field/property